# How to hide your selection on a shared file?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-sharing

I want to share a Google Spreadsheet document as view only, no problem doing that, but the issue is that anyone that views the sheet while I'm working on it can see the cells that I'm selecting (they appear with a green outline and show my name when they hover the cursor on them).

In Google Document you can actually change the file to "view mode", so there is no cursor displayed when you share it. But as far as I know, there is **not** this option on spreadsheet (I found out that it was possible in the past).

The most frustrating thing is that there is either no way to **not** have any cell selected, because if it were possible to just don't have anything selected, then there will be no problem.

The other "solution", of course, is to just close the page or log out or go in incognito mode on the browser, but I don't think I will call those real solutions, just ways to avoid the problem.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, as September 2019, Google Sheets doesn't include a way to hide the active owner/editors selection on the regular spreadsheet view.

Please submit your feedback to Google using [Google Feedback](https://www.google.com/tools/feedback/intl/en/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Create a new spreadsheet.
- In the top left cell use `=IMPORTRANGE(...)` to pull the appropriate page from your current spreadsheet.
- Repeat for other sheets from your existing spreadsheet.
- Share the new spreadsheet.

Comment: This is similar to the what the OP calls "ways to avoid the problem"